# Is hyphen (-) allowed in bash script arguments?

Tags: bash

I am writing a bash script and I want send a parameter to my script from outside which starts with a hyphen (-) like this '-d'.

However, I am getting following warnings when I execute my script

> dirname: invalid option -- 'd'

I am saying warnings as I can see my script is working despite of this. But I want to get rid of these warnings too. Can anybody help?

For more clarification, I am executing the script like this-

```
sh script.sh <param1> -d <param2>
```

Attaching a code snippet from the script where this argument is being used

```
case ${2} in
    -d|--days)      timeUnit="d";;
    -h|--hours)     timeUnit="h";;
```

Comment: Easier to see what's happening if you posted some code, some input, and some expected output.

Comment: In other words a [mcve] — : ) @Kusalananda

Comment: I have updated the post. Is it fine now?

Comment: The contents of `script.sh` and the expected output would be very useful.

Comment: @JonnyHenly Sadly I cant add entire script as its huge but I have added snippet where the argument is being used.

Comment: Could you also add the relevant `dirname` parts of the code?

Answer (score 5):

That is not a warning, it is an error.

If you want to pass a file name that begins with a dash to `dirname` then you have two options:

```
dirname -- -d
```

or

```
dirname ./-d
```

---

Based on your invocation line, we can infer that you must be incorrectly relaying the -d argument from your script's argument list to the argument list that is given to the `dirname` call that is being invoked from inside your script.

You're probably doing something like this inside your script:

```
dirname "$@"
```

or maybe

```
dirname "$2"
```

either of which will pass the -d argument to `dirname`.

You need to properly parse your script's arguments and only pass the *option value* of your script's -d option to the `dirname` call. This process is often referred to as *options processing*.

Here's an example of how you can do options processing:

```
dir='';
nonOpt=();
for ((i = 1; i <= $#; ++i)); do
    arg="${@:$i:1}";
    if [[ "$arg" == '--' ]]; then
        nonOpt+=("${@:$i+1}");
        break;
    elif [[ "$arg" == -?* ]]; then
        case "${arg:1}" in
            (d|dir)
                if [[ $i -eq $# ]]; then printf 'error: trailing -d option.\n' >&2; exit 1; fi;
                let ++i;
                dir="${@:$i:1}";
                ;;
            (h|help)
                printf 'script.sh [-h|--help] {param1} -d|--dir {dir}\n' >&2;
                exit 1;
                ;;
            (*)
                printf "error: invalid option: $arg.\\n" >&2;
                exit 1;
                ;;
        esac;
    else
        nonOpt+=("$arg");
    fi;
done;
if [[ ${#nonOpt[@]} -ne 1 ]]; then printf 'error: require 1 non-option argument.\n' >&2; exit 1; fi;
param1="${nonOpt[0]}";
if [[ "$dir" == '' ]]; then printf 'error: missing {dir}.\n' >&2; exit 1; fi;

dirname -- "$dir";
```

Comment: No, Its not a file name. The file name is valid so I am trying to execute the script like this "sh script.sh <param1> -d <param2>" @bgoldst

Comment: Yes it is a file name. The `dirname` utility takes file names as arguments. If it's not a file name, then you shouldn't be using the `dirname` utility.

Answer (score 0):

Hyphens are allowed in shell script arguments.

The warnings/errors are because you're passing that argument to another command that doesn't know what the `-d` option is.

You should [look into using `getopts`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial) to parse command line arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is what you do with the argument inside. Note that most of the programs treat the arguments starting with hyphen as an option so it does matter that you properly end the options with `--` prior to passing real argument.

In your case, assuming you pass `$1` to `dirname`, it should look like:

```
dir=`dirname -- "$1"`
```

Or if it was supposed to be real option to the shell, then you have to consume it first and remove, `shift` will do the work:

```
while [ $# -ne 0 ]; do
    case "$1" in
        -d)
             myoptionD=true
             shift
             ;;
        -*)
             echo "Unknown option: $1" >&2
             exit 2
             ;;
        *)
             break
             ;;
    esac
done
```

... or you can use `getopt` for this as well.